# Unexpected line wrap

Tags: html, css

A very simple html:

```
<div style="width:200px">
    <p>f 22222222222222222222222222</p>
</div>
```

will be rendered as:

```
f 
22222222222222222222222222
```

and what I was expected is:

```
f 222222222222222
22222222222
```

is it possible to fix this?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/8yL6j/
    ​

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you would like browsers to put as many characters on a line that fit there and then break, with no regard to normal line breaking behavior, rules of languages, etc., then use [`word-break: break-all`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/word-break) on the element.

Answer (score 1):

Use `word-wrap: break-word` to break the text up in the middle of a word:

```
.container {
    width: 200px;
    word-wrap: break-word;
}​
```

**Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8yL6j/1/**

Comment: the result is still not what I was expecting, I would expect that there is no new line after `f `